# How to access a variable that was available when an async method was called?

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

The animal names are fetched from an API that could return 404 if the animal is not found. But in order to properly log the error, we need to have access to the animal's country. Is it possible? I've read [something from a guy called Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-2-asyncstate-and-creationoptions.html) that made me think it is possible with lambdas, but I couldn't find anything.

```
var gettingNames = new List<Task<string>>();

foreach (var animal in animals)
{
    gettingNames.Add(this.zooApi.GetNameAsync(animal));
}

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(gettingNames);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var exception = gettingNames.Where(task => task.IsFaulted)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Exception.InnerExceptions).First();

    this.logger.LogError("The animal name from {Country} was not found",
        animal.Country); // This is the goal
}
```

Comment: You need a way to convert from the faulted task(s) back to the animal that sparked its creation. You might want to create a dictionary mapping from task object to animal to use in your exception handling.

Comment: You mean @StephenCleary? https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to project each `Animal` to a `Task` that contains more information than either a naked name or a naked error. For example you could project it to a [`Task<ValueTuple<Animal, string, Exception>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-3) that contains three pieces of information: the animal, the animal's scientific name from the `zooApi`, and the error that may have happened while invoking the `zooApi.GetScientificNameAsync` method.

The easiest way to do this projection is the LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) operator:

```
List<Task<(Animal, string, Exception)>> tasks = animals.Select(async animal =>
{
    try
    {
        return (animal, await this.zooApi.GetScientificNameAsync(animal),
            (Exception)null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (animal, null, ex);
    }
}).ToList();

(Animal, string, Exception)[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var (animal, scientificName, error) in results)
{
    if (error != null)
        this.logger.LogError(error,
            $"The {animal.Name} from {animal.Country} was not found");
}
```

Comment: I like this idea but, isn't this code awaiting for each GetScientificNameAsync consecutively instead of doing all at the same time concurrently? I mean, this would seem to be awaiting each time the return is evaluated and then, when the WhenAll hits, all the tasks were already resolved.

Comment: @user33276346 at first glance it may seem that the `GetScientificNameAsync` is invoked and awaited for each animal consecutively, but actually it is invoked concurrently for all animals. The `await` inside the selector of the `Select` operator does not await the projected `Task<(Animal, string, Exception)>`. It's an `await` inside the asynchronous lambda that generates this task. It may be difficult to get your head around it, if you are seeing this pattern for the first time. It's an example of the powerful technique known as "async-await composition".

Comment: The trick here is the `.ToList()` which causes the `.Select(...)` lambda to execute for each element, starting each task as they are added into the list.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I came up with a cleaner alternative based on your answer but I'm not sure it will work concurrently as yours, what do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392220

Comment: @JeremyLakeman wouldn't just it be called anyways with the whenall call?

Answer (score 1):

You have almost nailed it. :)

Rather than having a `List<Task<string>>` you need a `Dictionary<Task<string>, string>` structure:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var taskInputMapping = new Dictionary<Task<string>, string>();
    var inputs = new[] { "input", "fault", "error", "test"};
    foreach (var input in inputs)
    {
        taskInputMapping.Add(DelayEcho(input), input);
    }

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(taskInputMapping.Keys);
    }
    catch
    {
        foreach (var pair in taskInputMapping.Where(t => t.Key.IsFaulted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Value}: {pair.Key.Exception?.GetType().Name}");
        }
    }
}

static readonly ImmutableArray<string> wrongInputs = 
    ImmutableArray.Create("error", "fault");
static async Task<string> DelayEcho(string input)
{
    if (wrongInputs.Contains(input)) throw new ArgumentException();
    await Task.Delay(10);
    return input;
}
```

- `taskInputMapping.Add(DelayEcho(input), input)`: Stores the input next to the Task itself
- `taskInputMapping.Where(t => t.Key.IsFaulted)`: Iterates through the faulted tasks
- `$"{pair.Value}: {pair.Key.Exception?.GetType().Name}"`: Retrieves the input + the related error

Comment: I came up with an alternative but I'm not sure it will work concurrently as yours, what do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392220

Comment: @user33276346 Your solution is more flexible. If `GetNameAsync` requires not just one rather than 2 or more parameters then you don't need to modify too much. My approach needs further adjustment to allow that.

Comment: @user33276346 On the other hand your solution has introduced a wrapper method around the original request to make it fail safe. The exception stacktrace might look a bit weird because your wrapper is inside the `Select`. In my case the stacktrace remains the same as they were called sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

I combined the answers and came up with this:

```
var tasks = animals.Select(async animal =>
{
    try
    {
        return await this.zooApi.GetNameAsync(animal);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.LogError(error,
            $"The {animal.Name} from {animal.Country} was not found");

        return null;
    }
});

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var name in results.Where(x => x != null))...
```

Comment: That's OK. The difference with my answer is that, in your solution, the errors are logged concurrently as soon as they happen, while in my answer the errors are logged en masse on a single thread after the completion of all tasks. So your solution requires that the `this.logger` instance is thread-safe.